# Python - How to send index content to logstash with config ("%{@source}") in logstash.conf?

Tags: python, logstash, kibana

Well my boss asks me to send log to logstash, which is config to receive many different source and will put into many index.

Here is the config of `logstash.conf`:

```
input {
        #tcp {
        #       port => 5000
        #}
        udp {
                port => 5000
                workers => 4
                codec => json_lines
        #       buffer_size => 16384
        }
}

## Add your filters / logstash plugins configuration here
filter {
        mutate {
                lowercase => [ "@source" ]
        }
}

output {
        elasticsearch {
                hosts => "elasticsearch:9200"
                user => *******
                password => h************
                manage_template => false
                index => "%{@source}"
        }
}
```

You may notice the `index` was config  `index => "%{@source}"` for flexibility. But I dont know how to send `index` to this logstash.

From this source: `https://pypi.org/project/python-logstash/`

The sample code is here, but I dont know how to send index to `logstash`

```
import logging
import logstash
import sys

host = 'localhost'

test_logger = logging.getLogger('python-logstash-logger')
test_logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
test_logger.addHandler(logstash.LogstashHandler(host, 5959, version=1))
# test_logger.addHandler(logstash.TCPLogstashHandler(host, 5959, version=1))

test_logger.error('python-logstash: test logstash error message.')
test_logger.info('python-logstash: test logstash info message.')
test_logger.warning('python-logstash: test logstash warning message.')

# add extra field to logstash message
extra = {
    'test_string': 'python version: ' + repr(sys.version_info),
    'test_boolean': True,
    'test_dict': {'a': 1, 'b': 'c'},
    'test_float': 1.23,
    'test_integer': 123,
    'test_list': [1, 2, '3'],
    '@source':'apollo-staging'          #I add this in hope that it will work
}
test_logger.info('python-logstash: test extra fields', extra=extra)
```

Comment: I suggest you create an `stdout{}` output section, then paste what it produces into your question. Based on the information provided, it is unlikely that you have a `@source` field - this might be confusion around the [_source field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-source-field.html) in elasticsearch.

Comment: You mean add in the `logstash.conf` ? Is there any way to go around since some other sources (writen by PHP) can do it with current config. So it is hard for me to convince my boss to change the file `logstash.conf`

Comment: Adding an `stdout` section in logstash.conf will not affect anything else. But I understand that production can be hard to mess with.  
In any case, you should confirm that there *really is* a `@source` field

Comment: Alternatively, what do you expect the value of `%{source}` to be?

Comment: Well, I was told to add @source to my params sending to `Logstash`, I added but did not work

Comment: So, what do you expect the value of `@source` to be?